# setting string to array in KSH

Tags: linux, bash, ksh

I have a string which represents a list of files that are space-delimited.
for example:

```
 file1 file2 file3
```

I recieve this as a result of a `ftp ls` command  the output of the command is a list of files.

It is saved in a variable called `$CONTENT`.
I need the variable split to an array.
I've tried:

```
     echo "good count.."
     Files=($CONTENT)
     set -A STRING "$CONTENT"
     for x in $STRING; do
          echo "THIS FILE IS TO BE DOWNLOADED:  $x"
     done
```

in a command line this works perfectly.
In a `.sh` file executed, I get the: `set: -A: invalid option` error followed with the standard "how to use set command" verbage.

How do I work this?
Thanks!

Comment: `bash` and `ksh` are different shells. Use only the tag that matches your shell.

Comment: If the command works fine in the command line but it doesn't work in a shell script, make sure you are using the same shell for both.

Comment: It sounds like you're using `bash` for your interactive shell, but `ksh` for the script.

Comment: Doesn't a simple `l="a b c"; for x in $l; do echo $x; done;` do what you want? No need for an array, the spaces should suffice unless you quote the list variable (`for x in "$l"...` -- that is treated as one).

Comment: Isn't `Files` the array that you want?

Comment: Actually, I got that backwards. `set -A` is `ksh` syntax, but it doesn't work in `bash`. So you're running the script with `bash`. Change the `#!` line to specify the path of `ksh`.

Comment: Also, don't put quotes around `$CONTENT`, that will prevent splitting it.

Comment: wow.  this must be a record response time. Thanks alot all.  changing to ksh in the script worked!